# JAVA_HOME change automatically in Linux

Tags: java, linux

I set my JAVA_HOME path by using the command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

Then when I use this: `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

But when I close the terminal, and then open it and check `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the command will not get any result. That is, there is no JAVA_HOME set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` only makes available the variable to the current and child processes, it is cleared, when you terminate your process.

You may put your export command into your `~/.bashrc` file to have it always available.

So, open your `~/.bashrc` file with a text editor, and put this into the first line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
```

save the file, and after a relog, you can always use the veriable in shell scripts.

Other option (actually the recommended one by [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)) is to put this line into `/etc/environment`, this way the variable will be set for all users.

Answer (score 1):

to know java version use,      `java -showversion`

To verify java path is set or not use    `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Use following command to set java path

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

In the file set `JAVA_HOME`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/
```

remember to provide the path completely upto the folder which contains `bin/java`.

Restart system to activate the changes.